# Suppress PyQt event temporarily?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreewidget

I'm populating a branch of a QTreeWidget and then setting the expanded attribute on the parent of the branch to true. The itemExpanded signal fires in response, which is not what I want. Is there a temporary way to suppress or absorb signals during a segment of code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set blocking of signals using QObject::blockSignals. 
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qobject.html#blockSignals

> bool QObject::blockSignals ( bool block )
>   If block is true, signals emitted by this object are blocked (i.e., emitting a signal will not invoke anything connected to it). If block is false, no such blocking will occur.
>   The return value is the previous value of signalsBlocked().
>   Note that the destroyed() signal will be emitted even if the signals for this object have been blocked.
>   See also signalsBlocked().

Comment: Thanks. I presume then that I can fashion a `with` statement to block and unblock signals for a group of statements.